tensorboard line stops at some step

The blue curve stuck at step 152 while other curves showed up. Any possible cause for this to happen?
I am using pytorch with tensor board. The code looks like this:
        tb_writer.add_scalars(
            main_tag="Train/{}CacheRates".format(name),
            tag_scalar_dict={
                "HR": hr,
                "#AdmitsRate": (
                    (
                        admit_action.sum(dim=1).float()+1
                    ) / (
                        mask.sum(dim=1).float()+1
                    )
                ).mean(),
                "AskedToPrefetchRate": (
                    (
                        is_prefech.sum(dim=1)+1
                    ).float() / (
                        num_items.float()+1
                    )
                ).mean(),
                "PrefetchGiveupRate": (
                    (
                        (is_prefech * (prefetch_action == 0).long()).sum(dim=1)+1
                    ).float() / (
                        is_prefech.sum(dim=1)+1
                    ).float()
                ).mean()
            },
            global_step=run_step,
        )

